# Error when casting server.accept() to custom socket class

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, client

Ok so I have a class which extends to Socket and implements Runnable

On my server code. I did something like this.

```
ClientSocketAcceptedThread socket = (ClientSocketAcceptedThread) serverSocket.accept();
```

It runs the program. However every time a new client connecting to the server it says

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.net.Socket cannot be cast to Server.ClientSocketAcceptedThread
    at Server.ServerSocketThread.run(ServerSocketThread.java:45)
```

When I do something like this

```
ClientSocketAcceptedThread socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

It won't run the program and give an error

```
Error:(45, 57) java: incompatible types: java.net.Socket cannot be converted to Server.ClientSocketAcceptedThread
```

Can you help be what is the best approach in creating custom Socket class? Can you tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: Still I do not understand, have you overwritten serversocket.accept to return your socket type? ... because I suppose that your socket type is a child of socket, so not each socket is of your socket type

Comment: I found an answer on Discord chat. As what you have said "your socket type is a child of socket, so not each socket is of your socket type". I can't directly use my custom socket class that way. Instead I should instantiate it with Socket object and pass the object to my custom class constructor.